# Function composition, range and domain

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm not good with word problems, so any input would be appreciated.

A and B wrote letters in a code $f$ which consists of spelling every word backwards and interchanging every letter $s$ with $t$. Alternatively, they use a code $g$ which interchanges the letters $a$ with $o$, $i$ with $u$, $e$ with $y$, and $s$ with $t$.

a. Describe the codes $f∘g$ and  $g∘f$, are they the same?

b. What is the range and domain of these compositions?

a. $f∘g$ interchanges the letters $a$ with $o$, $i$ with $u$, $e$ with $y$, and then spelling every word backwards.

$g∘f$ spells every word backwards and interchanges every letter $a$ with $o$, $i$ with $u$ and $e$ with $y$.

They are not the same.

b. Domain of both is the letters of English alphabet, the range of both is the alphabet without $a$, $i$, and $e$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specific description in a is correct, but they are the same.  Let us take aces as the input.  $g(aces)=ocyt, f\circ g(aces)=syco, f(aces)=teca, g\circ f(aces)=syco$  The point is you can replace the letters before or after reversal with the same result.  I would say the domain is English words or strings of English letters as you are operating on the whole string.  The range is strings of English letters, and they can include $a,i,e$.  You would start with a word including $o,u,y$

Comment: Thanks! I just tackled it myself using a long sentence, and to my surprise came to the same conclusion that they are indeed the same!I guess I was thinking of substitution instead of interchange in case of a, i, e, for some reason. So all letters should be there.